# Ansible - x.x.x.x | UNREACHABLE! => { “changed”: false, “msg”: "Failed to connect to the host via ssh … }

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I created a cluster and i try to reach the master node from an another Ansible server. I copied the ssh key to the master server. and i can reach it via below command, from ansible server

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@x.x.x.x`

but i cant reach it with

`sudo ansible-playbook -i hosts /etc/ansible/playbook/test.yml`

And i took this error.

`x.x.x.x | UNREACHABLE! => { "changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection timed out\r\n", "unreachable": true }`

May you help me please? Other server fault issues didnt help me.

Note:

x.x.x.x (this is master node ip)

````
PLAY [nodes] ***************************************************************************************************************** TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************

ok: [t.t.t.t]

fatal: [x.x.x.x]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection timed out\r\n", "unreachable": true}

TASK [test] *********************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************

x.x.x.x : ok=0 changed=0 unreachable=1 failed=0

t.t.t.t : ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=1```
````

Comment: You seem to have two accounts based on an "answer" posted.  Accounts can be merged easily/  https://serverfault.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 0):

The ansible-playbook command probably fails because the path to the ssh-key is not defined.

Ansible recommends to use the ssh-agent:

```
$ ssh-agent bash
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

> Another way to add private key files without using ssh-agent is using ansible_ssh_private_key_file in an inventory file as explained [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#intro-inventory)

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/connection_details.html

Answer (score 0):

Long-shot; but it might be your key permission. Try with below:

cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh @ "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"

This gets me going with ansible everytime.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to set privileges to private key on your ansible server
sudo chmod 600 id_rsa
check you have copied public key to the manage node
sudo chmod 700 id_rsa.pub
check that your inventory file properly configured with correct ip
check your sshd_config file in manage node there may some issues
restart ssh server on both ansible main server and manage node

Answer (score 0):

per your connectivity test, you're using `ssh ...` (assuming that keys are setup correctly), you run ansible playbook using `sudo`, that may be the reason why...

I would recommend *NOT* use `sudo` at all, as Ansible doesn't require that and your `root` user may have different config vs your user, so try same thing w/out `sudo`, it should work)